# Эффективность выборки MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

**Всем привет!**

Интересует вопрос по поводу возможной нагрузки на сервер, возникающей в результате выборки полей из таблиц БД. В большинстве случаев принято выбирать данные из SQL БД в PHP примерно таким образом:

```
*_query("SELECT Field FROM Samples WHERE ID>10 AND ID<100000000");
while($data=*_fetch_row())
{
...
}
```

Так вот, собственно, хотелось бы узнать, насколько сильно это влияет на производительность, какую нагрузку на сервер дает и есть ли более продуманные альтернативы?

**Спасибо!**

Comment: вот кстати, да, что за необходимость в ста миллионах записей может быть?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, это для примера. Стандартный пример крупной выборки - это таблица с пользователями, в которой их немало.

Comment: ну и они все вам нужны? вы все стопицот записей собираетесь вывести на страницу пользователю или что? или тут php в метках указан в смысле демона какого-то, а не страничного сценария (сорри, неточно выразился, ну вы меня моняли я надеюсь:)?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, да, я понял. Собственно, вопрос, скорее, теоретический, нежели практический. На основе той информации, которую мне могут тут предоставить, я смогу оптимизировать запросы, выделяющие гораздо меньшее количество записей( например, несколько тысяч )

Answer (score 6):

Используйте [EXPLAIN EXTENDED](http://habrahabr.ru/post/98904/) увидите сколько и чего использует MySQL
Так же запросы с таким количеством строк будут довольно сильно использовать память
Можете вывести пиковое использование памяти:

```
<?php
echo "Memory usage: ".round(memory_get_peak_usage()/1024/1024, 3) ."Mb";
?>
```

Такие запросы на практике используются крайне редко, а если и используются, то запускаются через фоновое задание, например через cron и собирают временные/промежуточные данные. Пользователь долго ждать не будет пока вы соберете и обработаете все данные.

Comment: Спасибо, полезная информация)